# Is Iterator increment results a new iterator?

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

> When we add(or subtract) an integral value to (or from) a pointer, the
>   result is a new pointer. That new pointer points to the element the
>   given number ahead of (or behind) the original pointer: (**pp.119 c++ primer 5ed**)

I've also learned from the book, pointers are Iterators (**pp.118 c++ primer 5ed**).

**Question**

Can I also claim that the arithmetic operations on an iterator creating a totally new iterator.

Comment: What do you mean create? If you mean a temporary object being created when you do arithmetic operation on an iterator, yes it does. But how does that affect anything? Temporary objects are destroyed automatically when they go out of scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book describes a situation when you write, say, `p + n`, where `p` is a pointer and `n` is an integer. The expression produces a new value of pointer type. It is up to you to decide where to store the value; you can also decide not to store it at all.

Incrementing a pointer, i.e. writing `p += n`, changes the value of the original pointer to `p + n`.

The way it works for iterators is the same: `it + n` produces a new iterator, while `it += n` changes the existing iterator.

**Note** The first expression could be written as [`std::next(it, n)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next), while the second should be written as [`std::advance(it, n)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance), for both iterators and for pointers.

Comment: The evaluation of the expression  `it + n`  yields a new iterator. Thx.

Comment: See [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) for a complete definition about operations and corresponding return values/results.

Comment: See also C++ standard http://www.eel.is/c++draft/random.access.iterators

Comment: Ah... I think I understand it better now, Cant I say `std::next(it, n)` has no side effect while `std::advance(it, n)` has side effect.

Comment: @SLN Yes, that's exactly right - next has no side effect, while advance does.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks a lot for your explanation!

Answer (score 1):

> Can I also claim that the arithmetic operations on an iterator creating a totally new iterator.

Iterators in the standard library are designed to mimic pointers in their behavior, to an extent. So if you are talking about iterators that originate from standard library containers, then post-incrementing them (which will also modify the source), or adding numbers to them (for random access iterators), will result in new pure iterator values (or "new iterators" as you phrased it). And addition will not modify the source iterator in the standard library.

But since an iterator in general can be any user defined class, with its own overloaded set of operators, then there's no telling. Once can theoretically design an iterator, where the result is a reference to the existing iterator we supplied as an operand.

And as a matter of fact, even in the standard library, pre-increment returns a reference to the current iterator (in accordance to the behavior of pointers in C++).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, no and maybe. An iterator is what's called a "proxy object", that is an object that contains some metadata tied to some other object. In this case, an iterator attempts to behave like a pointer, at least kind of.

So, your actual iterator object will be exactly the same one (for example, if you set a breakpoint in the constructor for an iterator, it won't be called from `operator++` on the iterator). Giving the answer "no".

The iterator will have a different value inside it, and behave just like a different (aka 'new' in the quoted text) pointer. So it gives the answer "yes".

I'm sure we can discuss this a lot further, to conclude that the final answer depends on what you mean by the term "new iterator".

Comment: Agreed, `operator++` won't call the constructor but would `operator+(int)` call the constructor?

Comment: Plausibly, yes. The offical way certainly would be to call the constructor to create a temporary copy, and then modify the original, but the compiler is allowed to optimize that away. Since iterators are almost always templated, it's likely in practice to not create a new iterator unless you do something like `it2 = it++;` - I'm sure there are other similar examples, but generally, I'd expect `for(it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++) ...` to not call a constructor as a result of `it++` - unless the compiler decides that it can't figure out that it's benign to skip construction.